# Fedora 38 KDE Plasma ui acting strange

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, gui

I have noticed after installing Fedora 38 that sometimes UI elements like right clicking chrome to open a new tab will disappear as shown below.
Today I was switching through different applications when I noticed this echoing happening to my desktop (see below).

Is this an issue with KDE Plasma? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that indeed looks like a bug in the graphics stack / graphic card driver. Could you tell us which graphics card you're using?

Comment: I am using Intel TigerLake-H GT1 for graphics.